# Setting Bundle not outputting correct value

Tags: objective-c, ios, settings.bundle

Here's the issue, I launch my app from Xcode and it gets up and running then I switch to settings.app and change a toggle from NO to YES and when I switch back to my app, the key outputs NO not YES.

i think i'm running up against the quote below,  but not sure how to get around it, if the user launches the app, and goes to settings and changes the toggle, its now out of sync because Settings.app outputs on first launch to NO.  Doesn't make sense that a user can't change the setting the first time they switch to settings.app

"For newly installed applications, default preference values from the application’s Settings bundle are not set until the Settings application runs. This means that if the user runs your application before running Settings, the default values specified in your Settings bundle are unavailable."

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"NO" forKey:@"hideActionBar"];
[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];
```

and then the code i use to check it

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 BOOL hidden = [defaults boolForKey:@"hideActionBar"];
 NSLog(@"%d",hidden);

if (hidden) {
    viewController.actionButton.enabled = NO;

} else {


    viewController.actionButton.enabled = YES;
}    
}
```

and my settings Root.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"      "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Type</key>
<string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
<key>Title</key>
<string>Hide Action Bar</string>
<key>Key</key>
<string>hideActionBar</string>
<key>DefaultValue</key>
<false/>
<key>TrueValue</key>
<true/>
<key>FalseValue</key>
<false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `BOOL` variables you need not to set any value if want it to be `NO`. Because when you will try to access it first time it will return you the same. So remove `registerDefaults` code(all four lines) from your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

**Explanation:**

When you change setting from `NO` to `YES` and launch your application, in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  this value is once changed to NO programmatically.

**Note:** Whenever you use settings bundle in your application, prior to registering a value(object value, because primitive types will return 0) check whether that value is nil(it means still unregistered), if the value for key is nil then only register with  initial default values else you will end up in changing the values each time programmatically.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks a bunch, very helpful answer.  I've figured out that using fast switching going from Settings back to my app isn't writing to the  nsdefaults key fast enough for my app to see the new value. I'll have to figure out a way to workaround that, maybe if I add the background 10minute execution stuff or set a timer for a couple seconds before I check the key value.